# Problems inserting each item from ListView into sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I've problems with inserting item into database. I have 6 items in my ListView and created database for it. When I click a certain item to insert into database, 6 items are inserted instead of the certain item. I feel it is something to do with my insert codes.

Below is the insert codes for inserting item into the table of the database.

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        buddyDB.open();
        long _id;
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);

        /*TextView contactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString(); 

        TextView contactNameTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValueTwo  = contactName.getText().toString();

        TextView contactNameThree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValueThree = contactName.getText().toString();

        TextView contactNameFour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValueFour = contactName.getText().toString();

        TextView contactNameFive= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValueFive = contactName.getText().toString();

        TextView contactNameSix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        String NameValueSix = contactName.getText().toString();*/

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Selected: " + buddiesList[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Kanak Priya");
        _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Joanne Liew");
         _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Michelle Lam");
        _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Melissa Haiting");
        _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Teo Kin Hua");
        _id = buddyDB.insertContact("David Yeo");

        buddyDB.close();    

        Intent i = new Intent(context, PersonalInfo.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside "onListItemClick",

```
 TextView contactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
 String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString(); 
 id = buddyDB.insertContact(NameValue);
```

where, v = View, the parameter of the onListItemClick

Answer (score 0):

You insert 6 rows:

```
_id = buddyDB.insertContact("Kanak Priya");
    _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Joanne Liew");
     _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Michelle Lam");
    _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Melissa Haiting");
    _id = buddyDB.insertContact("Teo Kin Hua");
    _id = buddyDB.insertContact("David Yeo");
```

Comment: yeah, are there any other ways? I have even code this : TextView contactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);         String NameValue = contactName.getText().toString(); and id = buddyDB.insertContact(NameValue); which shows the first name of the list in the sqlite database browser despite which item i click in the list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are inserting six items each time you click either list item.

In your onListItemClick you need to do a check for which contact you clicked before you insert it into your db.

For instance:

```
_id = buddyDB.insertContact(NameValue);
```

and remove the six insert statements you have in your code.